# Copying value of multiple html Selects and a form to text area to submit to PHP script using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have multiple `<select>`s and one form I need to submit with one button. I'm trying to use a text area as a summary, which I will then submit to a script.

To move the form element I have this and it works fine:

```
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    document.getElementById('ordsumry').value = this.value;
});
```

I thought I could copy the script and replace the first ElementId to add other values to the text area but it doesn't seem to add the values from the selects.

If anyone does know how to submit them all with out a text area that would be great but bear in mind I have zero knowledge of AJAX.

Comment: The code above will change the value of the "ordsumry" element to the value of the "add" element. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: You want to put the input values into a textarea then submit the textarea in a form ? is that correct? why? ps. add a plus sign to stop overwriting the values `document.getElementById('ordsumry').value += this.value;`